# Fail to boot: Codepage not found

Tags: arch-linux, boot

I run arch linux and recently upgraded to kernel 4.6.9. Upon reboot, I was dumped into single user mode, with an error message that indicates a missing codepage, specifically codepage 437. I did some research, and it looks like cp437 is used to identify FAT file systems. I checked the options my kernel was compiled with (it is the default arch kernel) and `CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE`_437 was compiled as a module and `CONFIG_FAT_DEFAULT_CODEPAGE` was set to 437. The error `dmesg` gives is this: `FAT-fs (sdc1): codepage cp437 not found`. `/dev/sdc1` is my UEFI boot partition and is stored on a removable usb drive. I am unable to move beyond single user mode, which I find strange because the only volume I am not able to mount is the UEFI partition (I have tried mount it with the `mount` command, even specified the codepage).

I looked for answers on the arch linux bbs. What I have tried so far is mounting all of my drives and partitions to a live iso of arch and upgrading the entire system. I have read that recompiling the kernel may solve the issue but it seems like the necessary code was already compiled in. I am willing to try if need be. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The module should be on the initramfs. It sounds like something went wrong when upgrading the kernel and the initramfs wasn't regenerated properly. Check the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio), maybe it has a recovery procedure that could work for you.

Comment: Yes that worked! I am able to boot into multi-user mode (my default mode). Seems like quiet mode was enabled on boot, didn't get any status messages, and gdm hangs when I start it, but at least I'm not stuck in single-user mode. Thanks!