# failed to mount fat filesystem: codepage cp437 not found

Tags: filesystems, boot, fat

I am experiencing the same problem described here: [Fail to boot: Codepage not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345067/15010).

My error is: `FAT-fs (sdx1): codepage cp437 not found`

My fstab mount command for the device is:

```
LABEL=ESP /boot vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

The above is automatically generated by a script and it hasn't changed recently. The problem started recently.

I have already run `mkinitcpio -p linux` and it completes as expected without any errors. Other systems that are configured identically ([afaics](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/AFAICS)) do not have this issue.

I have checked the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio) as suggested at the comment by Gilles on the other question, but I don't find the specific problem.

Comment: Anything changed recently, e.g. system upgrade?

Comment: Yes, there was a recent system update which included a new kernel. But this update wasn't a problem on any of my other identically configured computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running Arch Linux. This problem can generally be resolved by including `vfat` in the modules list in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf. Here's an example:

```
MODULES=(nvidia vfat)
```

However, another way this same error message can occur is if you boot Arch with a kernel version that does not exactly match the version of the libraries on your system. That's how I encountered it. I resolved it simply by booting with the correct kernel version.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need a kernel that was compiled with `CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_437=y/m`.